# Issue on Re-Positioning Bootstrap Carousel Caption For Each Slide

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have custom position for each of the Bootstrap Carousel slides in [<kbd>This Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/9thw5mad/)

As you can see from the code the

```
.carousel-caption {
    top: 0;
    bottom: auto;
}
```

overwrites the original caption rule and bring the caption up but what if I need to re-presents the other  slides captions in other position?! I already tried this by adding a new rule through `.cap`

```
.cap {
    top: 50 !important;
    bottom: auto;
}
```

but not working! Can you please let me know how to fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
top: 50 !important;
```

try:

```
top: 50px;
```

This pushes the caption further down the carousel when I test it on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9thw5mad/3/).